# how to run docker container in background with custom entrypoint in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have created the below docker [file](https://github.com/rajcspsg/go-ethereum/blob/go-ethereum-ubuntu/Dockerfile).

```
FROM ubuntu:latest as builder

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
 INITRD=No \
 LANG=en_US.UTF-8 \
 GOVERSION=1.9 \
 GOROOT=/opt/go \
 GOPATH=/root/.go 
 RUN  apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y software-properties-common \
 && apt-get install -y wget \
 && apt-get install -y make \
 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
 && add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/gcc-7.2 \
 && apt-get update \
 && apt-get install -y gcc g++ \
 && apt-get install -y linux-headers-4.11.0-14-generic \
 && apt-get install -y musl-dev \
 && cd /opt && wget https://storage.googleapis.com/golang/go${GOVERSION}.linux-amd64.tar.gz && \
tar zxf go${GOVERSION}.linux-amd64.tar.gz && rm go${GOVERSION}.linux-amd64.tar.gz && \
ln -s /opt/go/bin/go /usr/bin/ && \
mkdir $GOPATH

ADD . /go-ethereum
RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/config \
   && mkdir -p /home/ubuntu/eth-dev \
   && mkdir -p /usr/local/scripts \
   && cd /go-ethereum && make geth

COPY --from=builder /go-ethereum/build/bin/geth /usr/local/bin/
COPY --from=builder /go-ethereum/scripts/entry-point.sh /usr/local/bin/
COPY --from=builder /go-ethereum/genesis/genesis.json /usr/local/config/

EXPOSE 8545 8546 30303 30303/udp
ENTRYPOINT ["entry-point.sh"]
```

The contents of [entry-point.sh](https://github.com/rajcspsg/go-ethereum/blob/go-ethereum-ubuntu/scripts/entry-point.sh) are

```
 #!/bin/bash
 geth --datadir /home/ubuntu/eth-dev init /usr/local/config/genesis.json 

 geth --networkid 45634 --verbosity 4  --ipcdisable --rpc --port 30301 --rpcport 8545 --rpcaddr 0.0.0.0 console 2>> /home/ubuntu/eth-dev/eth.log
```

When I build the docker image from docker file is it created successfully.
Then I run the docker image as container using below command

```
 docker run -d --name ethereum-ubuntu-geth-node2 ethereum-ubuntu-geth-node2
```

It creates the container and exits the container immediately. I'm not expecting this as I'm running the container in daemon mode(It should run in the background).

Below is the container status

```
$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                        COMMAND                  
CREATED             STATUS                    PORTS               
NAMES
0d25a5e71449        ethereum-ubuntu-geth-node2   "entry-point.sh"         
4 seconds ago       Exited (0) 1 second ago                       
ethereum-ubuntu-geth-node2
```

Below is the output of container logs.

```
$ docker logs ethereum-ubuntu-geth-node2
WARN [09-28|00:32:28] No etherbase set and no accounts found as default 
INFO [09-28|00:32:28] Allocated cache and file handles         database=/home/ubuntu/eth-dev/geth/chaindata cache=16 handles=16
INFO [09-28|00:32:28] Writing custom genesis block 
INFO [09-28|00:32:28] Successfully wrote genesis state         database=chaindata                           hash=a3c5c1…d6926b
INFO [09-28|00:32:28] Allocated cache and file handles         database=/home/ubuntu/eth-dev/geth/lightchaindata cache=16 handles=16
INFO [09-28|00:32:28] Writing custom genesis block 
INFO [09-28|00:32:28] Successfully wrote genesis state         database=lightchaindata                           hash=a3c5c1…d6926b
Welcome to the Geth JavaScript console!

instance: Geth/v1.7.1-unstable/linux-amd64/go1.9
modules: admin:1.0 debug:1.0 eth:1.0 miner:1.0 net:1.0 personal:1.0 
rpc:1.0 txpool:1.0 web3:1.0
```

> 

Below is the output of docker run interactive output.

```
$ docker run -it --name ethereum-ubuntu-geth-node2 ethereum-ubuntu-geth-node2
WARN [09-28|00:45:28] No etherbase set and no accounts found as default 
INFO [09-28|00:45:28] Allocated cache and file handles         database=/home/ubuntu/eth-dev/geth/chaindata cache=16 handles=16
INFO [09-28|00:45:28] Writing custom genesis block 
INFO [09-28|00:45:28] Successfully wrote genesis state         database=chaindata                           hash=a3c5c1…d6926b
INFO [09-28|00:45:28] Allocated cache and file handles         database=/home/ubuntu/eth-dev/geth/lightchaindata cache=16 handles=16
INFO [09-28|00:45:28] Writing custom genesis block 
INFO [09-28|00:45:28] Successfully wrote genesis state         database=lightchaindata                           hash=a3c5c1…d6926b
Welcome to the Geth JavaScript console!

instance: Geth/v1.7.1-unstable/linux-amd64/go1.9
modules: admin:1.0 debug:1.0 eth:1.0 miner:1.0 net:1.0 personal:1.0 
rpc:1.0 txpool:1.0 web3:1.0

>
```

Now when I check the container status it is up.

```
$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                        COMMAND                  
CREATED             STATUS                  PORTS                                 
NAMES
e27de43da867        ethereum-ubuntu-geth-node2   "entry-point.sh"         
12 seconds ago      Up 11 seconds           8545-8546/tcp, 30303/tcp, 
30303/udp   ethereum-ubuntu-geth-node2
```

Below are my docker details.

```
$ docker version
 Client:
 Version:      17.09.0-ce-rc2
 API version:  1.32
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   363a3e7
 Built:        Thu Sep 14 02:01:59 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.09.0-ce-rc2
 API version:  1.32 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   363a3e7
 Built:        Thu Sep 14 02:03:24 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: false
```

I want to do some `geth` utilities command in the shell once the container started and once I exit the shell still expecting the container to be running. Can I do that in anyway?

Answer (score 1):

You can run a container with stdin defined and detached at the same time. Though it's much better to configure your application to run as a server in the foreground without the need for stdin.

```
$ docker run -itd \
  --name ethereum-ubuntu-geth-node2 \
  ethereum-ubuntu-geth-node2
```

Comment: Yes. I tried it. But I didn't get interactive shell.

Comment: Did the container immediately exit?

Comment: actually I want to do some `geth` utilities and then quit the shell but container to be running. Can I do that in anyway?

Comment: A container is a method to run a process with added isolation (namespaces and cgroups). If you exit your entrypoint, you've exited your process, and you no longer have a running container.